# Variable inside a JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm very new to jquery and js, so forgive me if it's very easy.

I'm trying to make a ticker for cryptocurrency couples for the exchange liqui.

The API and everything works great, but I can't seem to put a variable inside a JSON request function: "dataResults.eth_btc.last" - I want the "eth_btc" part to be the variable "couple" so I can use any couples.

Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        var value = 0;
        var color;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function(){
            var couple = $("#couple").val();
            window.setInterval(function(){
                var url = 'https://api.liqui.io/api/3/ticker/' + couple;
                $.getJSON(url, function(dataResults) {
                        var newvalue = dataResults.eth_btc.last; //<<<This right here
                        if (!color) {
                            color = "blue";
                            value = newvalue;
                            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
                            document.querySelector("body p:last-child").id = color;
                            document.querySelector("#" + color).innerHTML = value;
                        } else if (value != newvalue) {
                            var colorid = $('#' + color);
                            colorid.empty().remove();           
                            if (value > newvalue) {
                                color = "green";
                            } else if (value < newvalue) {
                                color = "red";
                            }
                        value = newvalue;
                        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
                        document.querySelector("body p:last-child").id = color;
                        document.querySelector("#" + color).innerHTML = value;
                    }
                });
            }, 100);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <p>Koppel (eth_btc): <input type="text" id="couple" value=""></p>
    <button>Laatste prijzen</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: dataResults[couple].last

Comment: Thanks... That was incredible easy...